# Create search filter by users.IsApproved

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, filtering

I'm creating a search page in order to filter users by their usernames, approval status, and whether they're currently locked out or not.

```
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterby))
        {
            int totalRecords;
            if (filterby == "all")
            {
                viewModel.PaginatedUserList = Membership.GetAllUsers(page, pageSize, out totalRecords).ToPaginatedList(page, pageSize, totalRecords, searchterm, filterby);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchterm))
            {
                string query = searchterm + "%";
                if (filterby == "email")
                {
                    viewModel.PaginatedUserList = Membership.FindUsersByEmail(query, page, pageSize, out totalRecords).ToPaginatedList(page, pageSize, totalRecords, searchterm, filterby);
                }
                else if (filterby == "username")
                {
                    viewModel.PaginatedUserList = Membership.FindUsersByName(query, page, pageSize, out totalRecords).ToPaginatedList(page, pageSize, totalRecords, searchterm, filterby);
                }

                else if (filterby == "approval")
                {
                    viewModel.PaginatedUserList = (PaginatedList<MembershipUser>) Membership.GetAllUsers(page, pageSize, out totalRecords).ToPaginatedList(page, pageSize, totalRecords, searchterm, filterby).Where(x => x.IsApproved == false);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]' to type 'Project.Core.Pagination.PaginatedList`1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]'." whenever I try to search by approval.  Since I'm still learning, I'm not quite sure the best course of action to resolve this.  Any help would be appreciated.